# How to overwrite a group policy - homepage

Tags: windows-registry, group-policy, homepage

I'm in IT at my work but can't change the group policies. 
I want to know if theres a local script or registry change I can use that overwrites or changes the homepage policy.

Basically I just want it to go to Google instead of our companies' homepage because it takes too long to load.

The group policy takes priority so I figure it will have to run every time I log in, which is fine.

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: This does not override the home page, but it works even for users without admin rights. Instead of your starting your browser, start it with `C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe" https://google.com`  (Replace firefox with your browser of choice).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manually Override Power Settings in Windows 7 with a Group Policy in place](http://superuser.com/questions/475988/manually-override-power-settings-in-windows-7-with-a-group-policy-in-place)

Answer (score 2):

Group policies are assigned at login, so if a setting is changed post login it will be persisted till next log on.

With that in mind, and if you have local administrative privileges on your machine, you can use [this site](http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net/) to find out what registery key is associated with a group policy rule and update it. All you need to do is put the registery update as a batch script in your start-up folder and you will be able to override the homepage every time you log in.