# Turning Off Windows 7 Firewall

Tags: windows-7, windows-firewall

I need to temporarily turn off the firewall on my Windows 7 work computer, but the firewall settings are all greyed out.  Above them is a message saying "For your security, some settings are managed by your system administrator."

I have admin privileges on this machine.  How do I work around this?

Comment: You don't get around it since you don't have the privileges to disable the firewall.

Comment: Note that some organizations allow folks Admin privileges, but ask that they only run them when they need to. If you do have Admin, you can still do this. Go to `Start`, type `Services`, right click it, and `Run As Administrator`. You can then stop the service `Windows Firewall` even when group policy won't let you through the GUI. Remember to turn it back on when you've done what you needed.  Link: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/cannot-turn-on-firewall-wnew-hp-windows-7-machine/509a95e6-73cc-4faa-b746-1ab0ea5ccc98

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are on a domain and your domain administrator has disabled this via [Group Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_Policy).

To fix this you have two *legitimate* options:

- Open only the ports you need (if you have the privileges).
- Put a request in to the IT department to disable it/open the ports for you.

There are other [workarounds](https://superuser.com/questions/548247/how-to-overwrite-a-group-policy-homepage/548257#548257), however for something like the firewall I would **STRONGLY** recommend you do **NOT** use that work around and either do it one of the two *correct* ways I listed above. If you hack around the group policy you could get in trouble at work (possibly even legal repercussions if you [work for a bank or a government agency](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Computer_Fraud_and_Abuse_Act) or if you [live in California](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/California_Comprehensive_Computer_Data_Access_and_Fraud_Act))

Comment: Got it.  I'm currently working with Helpdesk to figure out how to either disable the ports I need or get it out of the way entirely.  Thanks for sparing me more "How do I run this as Admin, then?!" digging.

Do you mind a follow-up question?  Under "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security", I've created a new Inbound rule to allow all connections on port 8080.  It's not working.  Which do you find more likely: the theory that I'm doing something wrong, or the theory that my efforts are being trumped by the sysadmin-controlled settings?

Comment: There could be a `Deny` rule set by the group policy, or it just could be firewall weirdness. One thing you could do is (seance you are an administrator) in the run box of windows do `rsop.msc` This will show you your "Resultant Set Of Policies", it will let you browse and see exactly what group policy rules are being applied on you. If you are not an administrator (or you don't care for the GUI of rsop.msc) you can run `gpresult /V > polices.txt` from the command line, this will save the currently applied polices to a text file called "polices.txt" in whatever folder you ran the command from.

Comment: Oh, cool.  I can indeed run rsop.msc.  What am I looking for?  I've never used this tool before.

Comment: Anything in the `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Network\Network Connections\Windows firewall` path or the `Computer Configuration\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Windows Firewall with Advanced Security` path. If the folder does not exist, that means they did not set any rules up. You can use [this site](http://gpsearch.azurewebsites.net) to help search for where rules would be located.

Comment: Just checked a machine that I know has some firewall rules set up. Also check `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Extra Registry Settings`. That is where the firewall rules got saved that I set up in the "Windows Firewall with Advanced Security" GPO.

Comment: Thanks for your help, Scott.  I just posted a new question (http://superuser.com/questions/548574/connecting-to-work-machine) related to this one if you'd like to go for another checkmark.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

Firewall settings can also be defined via group policy. Either local group policies with the program gpedit.msc, or remotely via active directory on a domain controller.

Those firewall settings from group policy are also shown, but cannot be modified in the windows firweall settings.

The also cannot be seen in the expected place in rsop.msc. Instead they are there in Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, Extra Registry Settings (at least this is where I see them in Windows 7). They are in a text string which is difficult to interpret, but at least rsop tell which group policy they are coming from.