# Why can't I turn off the firewall?

Tags: windows, security, firewall, user-accounts, administrator

I became a laptop from my company. The OS is Windows 10. If I check my profile, it writes, that I am admin of the computer, but if I try to turn the firewall off, it writes: For your security, some settings are managed by your system administrator.

[Here writes, that I am administrator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0l1w6.png)

[Here writes, that my administrator manage the settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L5Xvd.png)

Comment: Are you by chance connected to an AD domain?  If you are then, while you are logged in as a local administrator, you are not likely an Administrator on the domain.  [You should also verify all the required services are actually running.](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-security/cannot-turn-on-firewall-wnew-hp-windows-7-machine/509a95e6-73cc-4faa-b746-1ab0ea5ccc98)[.](https://superuser.com/questions/548454/turning-off-windows-7-firewall)

Comment: "I became a laptop from my company." Sorry to hear that.

Comment: Reinstall Windows 10 on that PC.