# Screen saver disabled, but group policy shows it as "Not configured"

Tags: windows-8, screensaver

I am trying to enable my screen saver **wait time setting**, but it is grayed out (disabled). The local group policy seems to indicate that it should be enabled:

[image]

How can I enable the settings?

With the mystify ss selected:

[image]

*** UPDATE ***

It appears there is a group policy setting which is affecting the screen saver. The two settings are summarized in the below printout from `gpresult /Scope User /v`:

```
        GPO: Desktop Laptop Security Settings
            Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\ControlPanel\Desktop\ScreenSaveActive
                Value:       49, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled

            GPO: Desktop Laptop Security Settings
                Folder Id: Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\ControlPanel\Desktop\ScreenSaveTimeOut
                Value:       54, 0, 48, 0, 48, 0, 0, 0
                State:       Enabled
```

As a local administrator can I override these policies?

Comment: You can't change the "Settings..." if the Screen saver is set to "(None)". Choose a Screen saver and then you can configure it.

Comment: @DavidPostill Changing the screen saver selection makes no difference. I want to change the wait time.

Comment: Hmm. Works in Windows 7. Then I don't have those settings in the policy editor ...

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of that dialog with a screen saver selected (and made active by hitting "apply" after selecting one)?  Is this computer joined to a domain?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 I added the screen shot. It makes no difference which particular saver is selected.

Comment: Is this computer joined to a domain?  If not, try this: Control Panel -> User Accounts and Family Safety -> User Accounts -> Reset security policies.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It is joined to a domain. I have local administrator rights.

Comment: If it's joined to a domain, then you need to ensure no domain-level GPOs are affecting it/setting it.  Use `gpresult` (run as Administrator) to figure that out.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 Thanks very much, extremely pertinent. I have did as you said and there appear to be two group policies mentioning the screen saver active and coming from the domain. I have updated my question.

Comment: You should speak with your system admin about adjusting those.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Manually Override Power Settings in Windows 7 with a Group Policy in place](http://superuser.com/questions/475988/manually-override-power-settings-in-windows-7-with-a-group-policy-in-place)